# How to link url to an image in Github ReadMe?

Tags: github, readme

I have an url from another website that I want as a hyperlink to an image in my ReadMe

Comment: Does the image have an ID? What not use a _heading_ you can link to?

Answer (score 2):

You would use

```
![](<image url>)
```

Read this guide on Markdown for more help:
https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/